# Extensible ASP.NET MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, mef, asp.net-mvc-areas

I need to write a web application with ASP.NET MVC 3 that should be completely modular and extensible. A module/extension would be, for example - a forum, a blog or a content module.

I thought about using **multi-project MVC areas** for this purpose, so I have an `Extensions/` directory with the `.dll`-s of the extensions, and on `Application_Start` (or maybe on an earlier step), it loads all the extensions in that directory to current AppDomain.

Is there any *better way* to do this? I mean, maybe not using MVC areas at all? Maybe using MEF? I have a very little experience with MEF, and I'd like to learn, but I just don't know if that fits my project. Maybe using MVC Areas + MEF?

As you can see, I'm pretty confused and would like to have a clarification :)

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the SharpArchitecture and "Who Can Help Me" sample application. http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com/

Comment: Also, see this blog post Q&A about "Who Can Help Me": http://jamesbroo.me/who-can-help-me-q-a/

Comment: This pretty broad.  What are your requirements?  Your talking about exchanging views, the database and business logic.  Thats a pretty huge topic.  Who will be writing these modules?  Are you sharing users?

Comment: @Oded - I'll look into it tommorow, thanks. @jfar - I'm talking about exchanging the business logic only.

Comment: Take a look at Orchard (http://orchardproject.net). If it's not suitable for you then check out the code and you may get some ideas from how they do it.

Comment: I second looking at Orchard. It will give you some ideas as to how this can be achieved - Orchard itself is designed to be very modular in extensible in a fashion similar to the question you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into something similar. I've yet to start but so far I've read [this](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/07/27/ASPNET-MVC-3-and-MEF-sitting-in-a-tree.aspx) which seems promising.

It appears that MVC3 has specific interfaces for IoC, so you want to spend most of your time looking at MVC3+MEF examples. Some of the older examples are less relevant.

If you want your views to be easily extensible then [this](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/#axzz1Gkwl66Yk) seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've done quite a few topics on using MEF with ASP.NET MVC. It works quite well, but it is not as polished as say portable areas in the MVCContrib project.

MVC3 + MEF: http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=259

MVC2 + MEF: http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=159